# Can I key in the amount I want a layer to be moved in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, measurement

I know I'm able to <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> a layer in Photoshop CC and drag the layer and it will say how many pixels it's moved in a specific direction. But is there a way to just type the pixel distance into a directional moving area, similar to the behavior in Sketch?

Comment: Hi Colin, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

- Be sure to have `Window > Options` ticked;
- Select your layer;
- Hit <kbd>Cmd/ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ot choose `Edit > Free Transform`;
- Enter your desired coordinates into the X and Y fields in the Option bar.

[image]

Note that you can enter the specific coordinates of the reference point, the highlighted square in the diagram to the far left. You can change the reference point by clicking one of the other 8 squares.

Also note that you can do basic math in these fields. So if you want to move the layer by, say, 80 pixels, you can just type `+80 px` after the existing value. You can even key in other measurements and Photoshop will convert, like `233px + 2"`. You can use `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, respectively.